# How to get input text's value and pass it from child to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I try to change task which I have done before, input doesn't changes. Because it takes the value from `text` but not from object which I pushed in `tasks` array

**Component's code:**

```
const CurrentTaskInformation = ({
  status,
  text,
  deleteTask,
  changeStatus,
  editTask,
}) => {
  const [editMode, SetEditMode] = useState(false)

  const changeEditMode = () => {
    SetEditMode(!editMode)
  }

  return (
    <div className="row justify-content-center current-task">
      {editMode === false ? (
        <div
          onDoubleClick={changeEditMode}
          onClick={changeStatus}
          className="current-task-container"
        >
          <div className={status === true ? 'isDone' : 'isNotDone'}>{text}</div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <input
          autoFocus={true}
          onBlur={changeEditMode}
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => editTask(e.target.value)}
        />
      )}
      <button onClick={deleteTask}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CurrentTaskInformation
```

**Reducer's code:**

```
const initialState = {
  tasks: [],
  text: '',
  baseFilter: '',
}

const taskReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TASK: {
      let task = {
        id: shortid.generate(),
        text: state.text,
        status: false,
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: [task, ...state.tasks],
      }
    }

    case EDIT_TASK: {
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: state.tasks.map((t) =>
          t.id === action.id ? { ...t, text: action.newTask } : t
        ),
      }
    }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const addTask = () => ({ type: 'ADD_TASK' })
export const editTask = (id, newText) => ({ type: 'EDIT_TASK', id, newText })
```

**Parent component:**

```
{currentTasks.map((t) => (
  <CurrentTaskInformation
    key={t.id}
    tasks={tasks}
    editTask={() => editTask(t.id)}
    text={t.text}
    status={t.status}
    baseFilter={baseFilter}
    deleteTask={() => deleteTask(t.id)}
    changeStatus={() => changeStatus(t.id)}
  />
))}
```

Comment: From the above code it seems like you aren't passing id to editTask. Maybe you have more code that you haven't added

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Added parent's component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine except that you are not passing back the **new value**, `val` from the `CurrentTaskInformation`. You need this value because you are going to update the *Task* with *this new value*.

So, as also suggested in [Shubham Khatri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61959683/2873538), here is how you can pass the new value to update the task:

**CurrentTaskInformation component:**

```
<input
  autoFocus={true}
  onBlur={changeEditMode}
  value={text}
  onChange={e => editTask(e.target.value)}
/>
```

**Parent component:**

```
<CurrentTaskInformation
  key={t.id}
  // tasks={tasks}
  editTask={val => edit(t.id, val)}
  text={t.text}
  status={t.status}
  // baseFilter={baseFilter}
  deleteTask={() => __delete(t.id)}
  changeStatus={() => changeStatus(t.id)}
/>
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/todos-prhgs?file=/src/appSlice.ts).

---

**As you asked:**

> When I try to change task which i have done before, input doesn't
>   changes.. Because value takes from 'text' but not from object which I
>   pushed in array ...

I have few suggestions which you can make in your code:

- You can make the `input` field [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), use `defaultValue` instead of `value`.

```
<input
  autoFocus={true}
  onBlur={changeEditMode}
  defaultValue={text}
  onChange={e => editTask(e.target.value)}
/>
```

- Currently you are calling `editTask` on `onChange` event which gets triggered at every character you type in the field which makes firing many dispatch actions too. You can improve this by calling `editTask` on `onBlur` event or simply provide a separate button to save the changes. [`Debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) is also an option.

Let us know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass id and new value to the editTask function. At present you are only passing new value

```js
 <CurrentTaskInformation    
    key={t.id}
    tasks={tasks}
    editTask={(val) => editTask(t.id, val)}  // pass id and value like this
    text={t.text} 
    status={t.status}
    baseFilter={baseFilter} 
    deleteTask={() => deleteTask(t.id)} 
    changeStatus={() => changeStatus(t.id)} 
/>
```

Comment: Yes, I did like this, but I'm not totlly understand how I can put 'val' in present component)

Comment: val is being passed from CurrenTaskInformation component which you receive in arguments and add another parameter before calling the actual function

Comment: When I do this, the text is simply deleted

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: The rest of your code should remain the same. Could you please create a codesandbox

Comment: I can't create codesandbox, because there're a lot of components in my app...